# Create new textarea when current textarea reaches the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have a textarea pass along any overflowing text to another textarea which is added after the current one, **like how a word processor creates a new page when you reach the end of the current page**. I've thought about how to achieve this and the first thing that comes to mind is to add a new textarea after reaching the end of the current one and place the cursor at the start of the new one. The only thing is, I don't know how I would go about processing certain events such as:

- Select text across multiple textareas.
- Paste text near the end of one textarea and correctly split it so that part of the text is pasted in a new textarea.
- Remove empty textareas except the first one.

Is there an easier way I could go about doing this? Is there any way I could perhaps style a single textarea so that it just looks like there is a space between two lines to give the illusion that there are more than one textareas (that I could also style individually)?

Comment: I think perhaps you want `contenteditable="true"` http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/native-rich-text-editing-with-the-contenteditable-attribute

Comment: why do you need multiple textareas? If there's a lot of content, don't set a limit on the size of the content, just let the user keep typing and it'll scroll. Or are you trying to emulate a word processor specifically for some reason?

Comment: @ADyson I want my textareas to have a fixed width and height for a reason. To act like pages such as in a word processor.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishgoswmai/3uhNP/1018/)

Comment: @Eternity I see that, I was just wondering what the underlying reason was - there must be a reason behind "i want it like a word processor". I only say this in case there's another way to achieve the real end goal

Comment: Still I didn't find this kind of requirement anywhere so please check this link may it helpful to you http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/add-text.html

Comment: @Sukima's link seems to be the closest thing, I'll experiment with it. Thanks for all your help! :)